# Redux Thunk with Chrome Storage Return

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, redux, redux-thunk

I'm trying to get data from Google Chrome. Due to the synchronous operation, I can not send a payload to the payload part.

There is my **storageGet** function:

```js
export function storageGet(key)
{
        var privateData;
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            chrome.storage.sync.get(key, function(data) {
                privateData = data[key];
                resolve(privateData);
            });

        });
}
```

And there is my **getChromeInformations** action:

```js
export function getChromeInformations() {

    var eKey, aKey, authCheck;

    return storageGet("eKey")
        .then(function(_eKey){
            console.log("Begin the promise function");
            if("undefined" === typeof _eKey || _eKey == "" || _eKey == null)
            {
                var u1 = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2) + (new Date()).getTime().toString(36);
                storageSet("eKey", u1).then(function(response){
                    eKey = u1;
                });
            }
            else
            {
                eKey = _eKey;
            }
            return storageGet("aKey");
        })
        .then(function(_aKey){
            aKey = _aKey;
            return storageGet("authCheck");
        })
        .then(function(_authCheck){
                authCheck = "WHATEVER";
                console.log(aKey);
                console.log(eKey);
                return {
                    type: "GET_CHROME_INFORMATIONS",
                    payload: {
                        eKey: eKey,
                        aKey: aKey
                    }
                }
        });
}
```

And there is my **chromeReducer**:

```js
switch(action.type) {

    case "GET_CHROME_INFORMATIONS": {
        return {...state, aKey: action.payload.aKey, eKey: action.payload.eKey}
    }
```

So I can not get the data as asynchronous. How can I do that? If I run this code for a while, I get this error:

```js
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'payload' of undefined
    at Object.dispatch (background.js:1)
```

Comment: Note, getChromeInformations() currently doesn't return anything at all because there's no `return` before `storageGet`.

Comment: Thank you for warning @wOxxOm, i fixed this issue but still there is have same problem.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: Please don't give us multiple chunks of code with different functions. Give us code as files, with all the functions that are needed for a [mcve] in a single code block. Particularly with Chrome extensions, given that there may be multiple files, when you put just chunks of code, we have to start guessing as to what is in a file with each other. Note that your not doing so makes the Error you have shown provide much less information.  That error occurs on line 1 of *background.js*. None of the code you have provided appears to include a use of `.payload` in line 1.

Comment: Note: In `getChromeInformations()`, `storageGet("eKey", u1).then(...)` starts a completely separate train of asynchronous actions, as it is not included in the Promise chain which is returned. This means that `eKey` may not be correctly set when used later.